# Find the consecutively matched pattern index

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to find all the index of matched pattern in some string. For Example, I have a string `x <- "1110001101"`, I want to match it with `"11"`, **the result should be `c(1, 2, 7)`, however, I just can't get `2`**...

- Method 1: Use `gregexpr`

  ```
  x
  [1] "1110001101"

  gregexpr(pattern = "11", x)
  [[1]]
  [1] 1 7 # Why isn't there a 2?
  attr(,"match.length")
  [1] 2 2
  attr(,"useBytes")
  [1] TRUE
  ```
- Method 2: Use `str_locate_all` from package `stringr`

  ```
  library(stringr)
  str_locate_all(pattern = "11", x)
  [[1]]
       start end
  [1,]     1   2
  [2,]     7   8 # Why still isn't there a 2?
  ```

*Did I lose some subtle arguments for these functions?* Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Nice question! Just FYI, the documentation for `?gregexpr` says "`gregexpr` returns a list of the same length as text each element of which is of the same form as the return value for `regexpr`, except that the starting positions of every **(disjoint)** match are given." (my emphasis) So the behaviour is really just the implementation of `gregexpr`, not you misunderstanding regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround i.e. a positive regex lookahead to match a character followed by two 1's to give the positions of the start of the match with `gregexpr`

```
as.integer(gregexpr("(?=11)", x, perl = TRUE)[[1]])
#[1] 1 2 7
```

---

Or with `str_locate` either a regex lookbehind (in that case subtract 1)

```
stringr::str_locate_all(x, "(?<=11)")[[1]][,2]-1
#[1] 1 2 7
```

Or a regex lookahead

```
stringr::str_locate_all(x, "(?=11)")[[1]][,1]
#[1] 1 2 7
```

---

The difference between this approach and the OP's is that with the OP's approach, once the match is made, it skips that part and looks for the next match.  This can be better explained if we look at another string

```
x1 <- "11110001101"
str_locate_all(pattern = "11", x1)
#[[1]]
#      start end
#[1,]     1   2
#[2,]     3   4
#[3,]     8   9
```

With regex lookaround, there will be 4 matches

```
as.integer(gregexpr("(?=11)", x1, perl = TRUE)[[1]])
#[1] 1 2 3 8
```

Comment: Really cool, but I still don't know why my code can't show index `2`?

Comment: @WenhuCao  The  1st and 2nd positions got matched and you got the 'start', 'end' for that.  Then, it looks for matches from the 3rd position skipping the second.  You can check that with another vector `x1 <- "11110001101"
; str_locate_all(pattern = "11", x1)`

Comment: Ahh, I see, I need to read more on regexp, thanks again! But it seems that it would be reasonable setting pattern match element-wise for these functions ~~